# Uncompleted rendered images of Armadillo 3D mesh

Tags: python, pytorch, rendering, mesh

I'm trying to generate 2D views from a 3D mesh using the code in the link:
[code_from_here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-render-3d-files-using-pytorch3d-ef9de72483f8)

The code is written to treat a textured mesh, but I modified it to deal with an untextured mesh (Armadillo).

In return I had a rendered images of Armadillo 3D mesh that are uncompleted (see the pictures: [uncompleted rendered image of Armadillo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCz9a.png) ;
[uncompleted top 2D view of Armadillo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIkm2.png) ) and I couldn't figure out where is the problem!

I think that there are two important parts, the first one when I extract the informations stored in the mesh file (verts, faces) and the second is the settings  of the rasterizer witch is the one that take an image representation described in polygons or triangles (.obj file) and converting it into a raster image described in pixels (.png or .jpg file).

For the first part, I tried to do it without texture, so it turned from this:

```
# Get vertices, faces, and auxiliary information
verts, faces, aux = load_obj(
    obj_filename,
    device=device,
    load_textures=True,
    create_texture_atlas=True,
    texture_atlas_size=4,
    texture_wrap="repeat"
     )
# Create a textures object
atlas = aux.texture_atlas
# Create Meshes object
mesh = Meshes(
    verts=[verts],
    faces=[faces.verts_idx],
    textures=TexturesAtlas(atlas=[atlas]),)
```

To this:

```
verts, faces_idx, _ = load_obj(obj_filename)
faces = faces_idx.verts_idx

# remplacer la texure avec la couleur blanche
verts_rgb = torch.ones_like(verts)[None]  # (1, V, 3)
textures = TexturesVertex(verts_features=verts_rgb.to(device))

# Create a Meshes object for the teapot. Here we have only one mesh in the batch.
capsule_mesh = Meshes(verts=[verts.to(device)],faces=[faces.to(device)], 
textures=textures)
```

for the second part , I didn't modify it:

```
 # Initialize the camera with camera distance, elevation, azimuth angle,
# and image size
R, T = look_at_view_transform(dist=dist, elev=elev, azim=azim)
cameras = FoVPerspectiveCameras(device=device, R=R, T=T)
raster_settings = RasterizationSettings(
    image_size=image_size,
    blur_radius=0.0,
    faces_per_pixel=1,
)
# Initialize rasterizer by using a MeshRasterizer class
rasterizer = MeshRasterizer(
    cameras=cameras,
    raster_settings=raster_settings
)
# The textured phong shader interpolates the texture uv coordinates for
# each vertex, and samples from a texture image.
shader = SoftPhongShader(device=device, cameras=cameras)
# Create a mesh renderer by composing a rasterizer and a shader
renderer = MeshRenderer(rasterizer, shader)
```

Did someone encounter the same problem ?

Or can you take a look and give me your opinion please?

Here is the original mesh:

[3D_OBJ_Viewer_Armadillo](http://stlviewer.kwebpia.net/?state=%7B%22ids%22:%5B%2216H7ULS5DIKsbQTz5Cy5sdYM4Kb14_-5o%22%5D,%22action%22:%22open%22,%22userId%22:%22110912932056560866411%22,%22resourceKeys%22:%7B%7D%7D)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, you should include relevant code if possible in the body of your question

Comment: Hi Kevin, I tried to do so , is it clear or should I put the whole  code?